# Reload JS and CSS files on Jetty Server

Tags: javascript, css, jetty

I'm using Jetty Server. So far everything is going well. The main issue is when I change something on my css and js files. Jetty keeps serving the old copies of them. At some point it starts to serve the correct one but it takes a long time until it happens.

I tried to do what is suggested here - https://blog.michaelscepaniak.com/jetty-auto-reload-javascript-and-css-files - but it was useless.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the cached copies are coming from Jetty, and not the browser or another source?

Comment: How can I check where the copies are stored and where they are coming from?

Comment: You can use the network tab in the Chrome dev tools to determine if the file was loaded from cache. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31352554/1701316) for details.

Comment: Yes, it is coming from where it is supposed to come.                           Request URL: http://localhost:9001/WAR/views/css/nestable/spriteSetStyle.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)

Comment: (from disk cache) indicates that you're getting a cached copy from the browser, not from the Jetty server.

Comment: :( - how can I get it from jetty?

Comment: No worries, I'll post an answer here.

Comment: Please describe your Jetty setup.  Are you using jetty-distribution? embedded-jetty? something else? (spark java, spring-boot, embedded rest server? etc).   I ask this, as default Jetty configuration does not report HTTP response cache headers, you have to specifically configure your Jetty instance to enable that.

Comment: Hi, I'm using jetty-distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've seen out of the Chrome dev tools, you're getting a browser-cached copy of the files. You'll need to indicate to Jetty that it should send no-cache headers to the client. You can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26218880/1701316).

Comment: Default Jetty configuration has no cache control headers or etags, you have to specifically do extra work to enable those features.   If the OP didn't configure for the cache-control/etags, and they see those response headers, then something outside of Jetty's control is setting those headers.  (eg: jersey / spring static file serving)